# Find all functions $f(x)$ such that $f(x)+f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=2 x+4$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Here we have
> $$f(x)+f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=2 x+4$$ Find the function $f(x)$.

Firstly, I let $t=\frac{x}{x-1}$ then I got the equation
$$f\left(\frac{1}{t-1}\right)+f(t)=\frac{4t-2}{t-1}$$
After that I don’t find any notices to do more.

---

Please kindly give me a hint . Thank beforehand!

Comment: Hint: Substitute $(x-1)/x$ in place of $x$ to obtain a second equation, then do this substitution again to obtain a third one. Solve the resulting system.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you some hints to can work with.

1. Replace $x$ by $1 - \frac{1}{x}$ throughout to get another functional equation.
2. In the new equation you obtain, replace $x$ by $1 - \frac{1}{x}$ again!

Why is this a good idea? Note that
$$1 - \frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{x} \right)} \right)} = x$$
and
$$1 - \frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{x} \right)} = \frac{-1}{x-1}$$
You'll be left with three equations, where you can eliminate $f(1-\frac{1}{x})$ and $f(\frac{-1}{x-1})$ (the usual way of solving a system of linear equations) and obtain $f(x)$.